# How does squaring a function affect it's removable singularities?

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a simple question. say you have a function, f, with a removable singularity. does f^2 have a removable singularity at the same point?
I strongly suspect that squaring the function would only increase the multiplicity of its singularities, but I don't know this for sure and I can't seem to find a proof of this.
for example: f(z)=z/sin(z) has a removable singularity at 0, does this imply that [z/sin(z)]^2 does also?

Comment: I recall that the order of poles at $a$ of $f \cdot g$ is the order of the pole of $f$ at $a$ plus the order of the pole of $g$ at $a$. And $0+0=0$. Also if you look at the series expansion of $sin^2$ the leading term will be of order $1/z^2$. So the singularity at $0$ will again be removable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does.

Let $D = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : 0 < |z - z_0| < r \}.$ If $f : D \to \mathbb{C}$ has a removable singularity in $z_0$, then there is such holomorphic $g : D \cup \{ z_0 \} \to \mathbb{C}$ that $f(z) = g(z)$ for all $z \in D$. Therefore $f(z)^2 = g(z)^2$ on $D$, so the singularity of $f^2$ can be removed.

In fact, from the point you have $g$ you can forget there was ever a singularity in $z_0$.